# regular expression to find method name

Tags: regex

in my file, I have lines like below

```
myVar
myMethod()
```

I want to find string which has got '(' (method names only).  I have tried below regex but it satisfies for myVar too.  Can you please suggest appropriate regex?

```
[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\(*
```

Thanks

Comment: I have found solution as below

 [a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+[(]
 
Please suggest if better alternative is available.

Thanks!

Comment: Check the answer below. Why are we using the `+` in the first alphabet match ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is getting matched because of the star at the end.
Try This : `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+\(`

Also note that I have removed the first '`+`' as it is not required.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  A small issue though is if I have a method name with single character (-- like a("hello world") ) then it fails to match (though it is not a major issue right now but just wanted to know the solution).  Appreciate your response.

Comment: then match the alphanumeric by 0 or more i.e. `*` instead of matching 1 or more via `+`. I suggest you read the regex tutorial for the language you are using.

Comment: Underscores would be useful.